# Xquery how can I get the xml file with all the nodes using filtering in more than one elements?

Tags: xquery, basex

if I use the following request

```
collection('vagelisdb')[SensorInfo/Position/x>4]
```

I can receive all the nodesof the xml that fullfill my expectations of x>4

but it does not work I want to filter in one more node that is deeper

```
collection('vagelisdb')[SensorInfo/Position/x>4/anothernodename/y<2]
```

I want to receive only the nodes that fullfill x>4 and y<2 expectations but I want the whole xml. This means also the nodes that are starting from SensorInfo

In order to give some more details the xml is like this

```
<SensorInfo>
    <Position>
        <x>2</x>
        <anothernodename>
            <y>3</y>
        </anothernodename>
    </Position>
    <Position>
        <x>5</x>
        <anothernodename>
            <y>1</y>
        </anothernodename>
    </Position>
</SensorInfo>
```

And I want to receive

```
<SensorInfo>
    <Position>
        <x>5</x>
        <anothernodename>
            <y>1</y>
        </anothernodename>
    </Position>
</SensorInfo>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `and`:

```
collection('vagelisdb')[SensorInfo/Position/x>4 and SensorInfo/Position/anothernodename/y<2]
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. It returns all the data without taking to account if y<2.
I would like to receive only the SensorInfo that has x>4 and y<2.

Comment: @vagelis You didn't provide enough information initially to know what XPath to use. My answer has been updated to reflect the updates to your question.

Answer (score 0):

To select the `Position` nodes you want:

    `collection('vagelisdb')/SensorInfo/Position[x>4 and anothernodename/y<2]`

To wrap these results in a `SensorInfo` element you can use

    `element SensorInfo {
      collection('vagelisdb')/SensorInfo/Position[
          x>4 and anothernodename/y<2]
    }`

Comment: The problem is that I have namespaces declarations in the SensorInfo element and then I get the namespaces declarations in Position element

Comment: This can be irritating but those unused namespace declarations will not do any harm. If you must remove them  for some reason you could use a function like `strip-ns` see [xquery-how-to-remove-unused-namespace-in-xml-node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23002655/xquery-how-to-remove-unused-namespace-in-xml-node)